# How to add a button to a panel using a method and access it from the main?

Tags: java, methods, javafx

Let's say I want to create a method that adds a button to a `StackPane`. then I want to access to that button, for exemple I want to add an `EventHandler` from the main:

```
public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws ParseException {       

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        addButton(root);
        // HERE I WANT TO ADD AN EVENT HANDLER TO b BUT I CANNOT ACCESS IT
        // b.addEventHandler(); 
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void addButton(StackPane sp){
        final Button b = new Button("Test");
        sp.getChildren().add(b);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since button is local to your `addButton` you need to have a reference to it. Return the reference of your button from `addButton` method and use it.

It would be better to use it this way

```
public Button addButton(){
     //create Button
}
```

You can add this button to the `StackPane` in your `start()`

**Alternatively**,

*This approach is not recommended.*

You can get the `Button` out of the StackPane

```
Button  button = (Button)root.getChildren().get(0);
```

**N.B.** *Use this only if you are sure of the position of the Button*

### UPDATE

If you just want to separate your design from the action performed by the controls, JavaFX provides an eligant way to do it, using [FXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/why_use_fxml.htm).

It helps you to design the UI without any indulgence of the actions that they need to perform. And later, these FXML's can be binded to their actions through Controllers(Java Interface)

Comment: What if I have several Buttons, Labels, TextFields to add to the root panel and I want to create a method setUpGUI() thant creates and put my objects on the panel and then i want to create a method that add listener to some of these objects? I hope my question is clear :)

Comment: How are you gonna decide which listener is to be added to which button ? To avoid this confusion actions on buttons are written where they are created. Still if you want to achieve this you can run a loop on `root.getChildren()` and check whether its an instance of `Button`, if yes, apply whatever logic you have to separate one button from another and add a listener to it

Answer (score 1):

Add event handler to the button when you creating the button

```
public void addButton(StackPane sp){
    final Button b = new Button("Test");
    b.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
       @Override 
       public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                //your logic
       }});
    sp.getChildren().add(b);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good solution but not what I really need. Let's say I have to be able to refer to b from the main.

Comment: You can use `e.getSource()` or you could call in `handle` a method of main with `b` as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Scope the UI controls to the instance of the application class, instead of making them local to the method.

```
public class Test extends Application {

    private Button b ;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        addButton(root);

        b.addEventHandler(...);

        // ...
    }

    private void addButton(Pane pane) {
        b = new Button("Test");
        pane.getChildren().add(b);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Or, if you really want to separate the layout from the event handling, do the layout in FXML and inject the controls into a controller class, which can be responsible for the event handlers.